# Align two divs side by side

Tags: css, html

I have three divs.. Container, Content_1 and content_2.

What I want to do is position the two content divs inside the container, side by side. now I have half accomplished that.. But the thing is I want my container to automatically resize to the div that is highest. so the container height must be auto. With the code I have written on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UewK8/3/), the content_2 on the right sets the container height, but the content_1 on the left does not.. Please help I am completely stuck.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div id="content_1">

</div>

<div id="content_2">

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UewK8/3/)

Comment: Try adding `overflow:auto;` to css for .container. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wanted?

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UewK8/4/)

```
.container {
    background-color: #000; 
    width: 980px;
    min-width: 980px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 100px auto;
    top:60px;
    bottom:900px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto; /* <========= */
}
```

Comment: For some reason this works in JsFiddle, but when I add my overflow:hiiden to my website, content_2 positions itself underneath content_1.. Any suggestions?? And thanks..

Answer (score 0):

your divs closing tag is open: `</div` to `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you forgot the clearfix. There are a couple of ways to do a clearfix on google, but the one that will fix this problem is adding overflow:hidden to your container div.

Check out my example on http://cdpn.io/sEwfI

```
 .container    
     overflow: hidden;
```